# Spark error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE when reading large zip file

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use Spark ( 2.1 on EMR ) process ~500M gz files, I have no way to change the format nor split them to smaller sizes.

One of the executors is failing with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:869)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1303)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getLocalValues(BlockManager.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:698)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I understand that since gz is not splittable a single task handles an entire file, is there any way to avoid the error somehow?

Answer (score 3):

The error turned out to be not directly when reading the data but from processing after.
I added a repartition step which solved the problem.

Comment: Where did you add repartition step? Just before action?

Comment: First thing after creating the rdd.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to overcome the issue. I think spark has an issue open for this. Hope to get that resolved in next release or so.